# How to connect a motor shaft to a plate

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, torque, power-transmission, coupling

I'm trying to drive an aluminium plate using a motor via a 20mm-wide 2mm-thick stainless steel tube. The tube is driven by a 6mm motor shaft via a pulley and the torque will be around 5Nm at most. Is it a good idea to attach the plate to the tube with a split collar like [this](https://shaft-collars-couplings.staffordmfg.com/viewitems/flanged-mounting-collars/accu-flange--shaft-mounting-collars)?

[image]

However it's not clear what the rated torque and axial force are. If this isn't a good way, what might be an alternative without welding or adhesive?

Comment: This looks pretty typical to me. But without details of what the plate is doing, what forces it will see, what your bearing arrangement is, a data sheet for this part etc, we can’t help much more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be overkill in your application (but I don't know).

[image]

*Figure 1. A random rigid flange coupling from an image search.*

A rigid flange coupling may be a more economic choice if it suits.

---

From the comments:

> What are the benefits of a rigid flange compared to a split flange beside costs? Doesn't the flexible coupler give more friction?

A [flexible coupler](https://www.google.com/search?q=flexible+coupler) is something different. A [split collar](https://www.google.com/search?q=split+collar) is also something different to your picture which is, as far as I know, a [taper lock flange coupling](https://www.google.com/search?q=taper+lock+flange+coupling). The latter will be better in that it will be self-centering, give even grip around the circumference and over a length of shaft.

Comment: Right. What are the benefits of a rigid flange compared to a split flange beside costs? Doesn't the flexible coupler give more friction?

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of ways to connect to the shaft of a motor,  A few examples:

- set screw/grub screw
- through taper pin
- interference fit
- split ring
- taper lock
- welded
- keyway & key (most common industrial use)

Each of these has a torque spec that I think you can find in a mechanical engineer's handbook.  There are probably decades old free ones on the internet which are fine.  These are not new technologies.