# Secure loads to gearbox shafts

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, structures, bearings

I have a sculpture that is designed to rotate over 3 axes at max. 30RPM and is mounted on an aluminium disc. My plan is to use 3 of [these geared steppers](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/precision-planetary-gearbox/nema-17-stepper-motor-l39mm-gear-raio-501-high-precision-planetary-gearbox-17hs15-1684s-hg50.html?sort=p.price&order=DESC) and secure the sculpture to the Z-axis shaft, but it's not quite clear to me how to (economically) secure the motors and the load to provide 3-axis movement. I see that the maximum radial and axial loads are around 150N, and because the load is around 8kg, I could perhaps save myself from using additional bearings and just rely on the bearings in the gearboxes. Is it correct that if the load is accelerated and decelerated slowly (<1.88m/s^2), the 150N force limits won't likely be exceeded?

My current plan is to mount the Y-axis motor to the shaft of the X-axis motor using a shaft flange like [this](https://ozrobotics.com/shop/8mm-key-hub-18024-high-quality-universal-aluminum-hubs-are-key-locked/):

[image]

Similar for the Z-axis motor. However, the force figures of these flanges are usually not provided. Also there doesn't seem to be a good way to limit axial movements of the flange. I've thought about using circlips, but I'm not sure if they have sufficient strength to resist a 8kg load.

Does anyone know of a good way (or a good reference) for providing 3-axis movement to a 8kg load? Is it reasonable to expect the bearings in the gearboxes to adequately support the load, given the 150N axial and radial force ratings?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Similar to this? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/36152/10902

Comment: @SolarMike Yes and no. It's not clear if flanges like this have the appropriate force ratings. Also, how could axial movement of the flange be restricted? Circlips may not be strong enough. And it's not clear if the gearbox shafts can support the load.